# Как сделать выборку объектов, у которых хотя бы один связанный объект содержится в списке?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

```py
class Station(models.Model):
    #some fields

class Route(models.Model):
    #some fields
    station_list = models.ManyToManyField(Station, related_name='route_list')

class User(models.Model):
    #some fields
    route = models.OneToOneField(Route, related_name='user')

station_list = [st1, st2, st3]
```

Как можно сделать выборку по модели `User` объектов, у которых в поле `route` есть хотя бы один объект класса `Station` из списка `station_list`?

Пробовал сделать так, но не работает

```py
User.objects.filter(route__station_list__in=station_list)
```

Comment: Пробовали так: `User.objects.filter(route__station_list__in=station_list)` или так: `User.objects.filter(**{'route__station_list__in':  station_list})` ?

Comment: @VladimirGoncharuk, неправильно скопировал, поправил. Но это ведь одно и то же, в любом случае работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге объединил между собой несколько `Q` через `|` и использовал это в качестве запроса для выборки.

```py
from django.db.models import Q

search_query = Q()
for station in station_list:
    search_query |= Q(route__station_list=station)

result = User.objects.filter(search_query)
```